# AttributeError: 'Dedupe' object has no attribute 'sample'

Tags: python, csv, python-dedupe, dedupeplugin

I was running the [csv_example.py](https://github.com/dedupeio/dedupe-examples/blob/master/csv_example/csv_example.py) from dedupe-examples.

I got an error message as below

```
File "csv_example.py", line 111, in <module>
    deduper.sample(data_d, 15000)
AttributeError: 'Dedupe' object has no attribute 'sample'
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: if you're having trouble running someone else's code, it might be better to create an issue in their github repository or otherwise reach out to them to see if they can figure out the problem

Answer (score 0):

from dedupe import labeler

try labeler.sample(data_d,15000)
had same problem,sample is inside labeler file of dedupe, this worked for me

Answer (score -1):

I was facing the same problem while trying to run csv_-example.py.
I found out that you need to replace:

deduper.sample(data_d, 15000)

with

deduper._sample(data_d, 15000)

You need to put an underscore and I think it will work as it happens to me.